# How is the upper and lower cutoff frequency found here?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image: Text]

I got this from an IEEE journal (letter) regarding high frequency LLC converer control.

Comment: where is the figure?

Comment: The text describes how they solved the roots of the denominator

Comment: Circuit : https://i.ibb.co/nwb5hgT/sr3.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the two cut-offs are far apart, and consider the cutoffs at V/I = G/2.

Set s=0 ("very low") for the Ls/(N^2R) terms, and the G/2 cut off is where 1/(RCs)=1.

This is observed by examining the numerator.

Set s=inf ("very high") for the 1/RCs term, and the G/2 cut off is where Ls/(N^2R) = 1.

The concept of a cut-off shows when s approaches s=0 or s=inf and the transfer function is dominated by the surviving terms.